# wrong syntax while deleting duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I'm trying to delete duplicates using below code:

```
delete [TABLE] f
where id not in (select min(id) 
                 from [TABLE] s
                 where f.companyid = s.companyid
                 and f.value = s.value)
```

However, it gives me below error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'f'.

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Which RDBMS ? .

Comment: delete FROM [TABLE] f ?

Comment: it's MS SQL Server, version 11.0.6020.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, I like to use CTEs and `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by companyid, value order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

But the problem with your syntax is that it should start:

```
delete f from [TABLE] f
    where . . .
```

In other words, table aliases are defined in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Regarding your first advise, I'm gonna try too, however, why do you like it more? it seems too complicated.

Comment: @Turpan . . . Somehow, I just find the intention of the query to be clearer than using the subquery version.  I do note that this is not standard SQL, so it is only supported by SQL Server (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

```
delete  from  [TABLE] f
where id not in (select min(id) from [TABLE] s
where f.companyid = s.companyid
and f.value = s.value)
```

Comment: this it the same I've written :)

Comment: you had missed 'from' what is your table name?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE] f 
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT MIN(id) FROM [TABLE] s
                  where f.companyid = s.companyid and f.value = s.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

delete from f where id not in(select min(id) from  s where f.companyid = s.companyid and f.value = s.value);

TRY IT.

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because wrong wrong usage of alias the table. To alias your table with delete statement you can use;

```
delete f from [TABLE] as f
where id not in (
    select min(id) from [TABLE] s
    where f.companyid = s.companyid
    and f.value = s.value
)
```